# Transforming a Rose Tree in Scala

Tags: scala, breadth-first-search

[This posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47026183/553865) shows how to traverse a rose tree in Scala. I want to do something similar: invoke a method on every `CNode` in a rose tree. Here is the `CNode` definition:

```
case class CNode(
  name: String,
  helpMessage: String = "",
  children: List = Nil,
  alias: String = ""
)
```

Here is the method definition:

```
def node(objects: AnyRef*): SomeReturnValue
```

Here is some test data:

```
val cNodes = List(
  CNode("account",
    helpMessage = "Account management", children =  List(
      CNode("import", children = List(CNode("<keyfile>"))),
      CNode("list",   helpMessage = "List accounts"),
      CNode("new",    helpMessage = "Create a new account"),
      CNode("update", children = List(CNode("<accountAddress>")))
    )
  ),
  CNode("javascript"),
  CNode("help")
)
```

So, what I want to accomplish is to transform the above `List[CNode]` into a recursive call structure like this:

```
val result = List(
  node("account", children = List(
    node("import", children = List(node("<keyfile>"))),
    node("list"),
    node("new"),
    node("update", children = List(node("<accountAddress>")))
  ),
  node("javascript"),
  node("help")
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cycling home I realized there is a really easy way to solve the problem:

```
implicit def cNodeToNode(cNode: CNode): Node = 
  node(cNode.name :: cNode.children.cNodes.map(cNodeToNode).toList: _*)
```